# Is there a way to toggle paintbrush in Photoshop by holding a key down?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I just had an idea and not sure if its possible. Can toggling the Paint Brush be done with a keyboard button instead of the mouse?

Say I hold the <kbd>B</kbd> key down with my off-hand while drawing using the mouse in my good hand.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how?

Comment: Not sure I understand, you tap the `B` to swtich to the brush tool.. tap another key to switch to a different tool. As far as I'm aware the rotate canvas `R` and `Move tool (Command/Ctrl)` are the only on-the-fly tools.

Comment: Yes B is to switch to Brush tool by default. I want to know if there's a way so that as long as I hold the B key down it works like the LMB. So if I want to draw I can hold the B key down with one hand and use the mouse in the other.

Comment: I'm not understanding, what do you expect to happen by holding down the B key? LMB? I'm not grasping what *additional* functionality you are seeking.

Comment: @Scott I select the Paint Brush. In order to use it you must hold down either the LMB or RMB. For me, and most probably, its LMB. Instead of holding down the LMB the entire time I want to hold down a key, any key. B was just an example key.

Comment: Oh so you simply want to paint without holding a mouse button. No, I don't think that's possible unless you get a tablet. (FYI.. no clue what "LMB" was at first.)

Comment: I guess if you'd set B button, some key combination or macro key to serve as mouse button 1, then yes. If your keyboard doesn't come with application that can do that sort of stuff, there are third party applications that will let you do that. But I have to ask why?

Comment: @joonas to avoid extended discussion here lets take it to chat

Comment: @Ryan did this help with your drawing? I've been looking for a solution like this myself to better simulate freehand drawing on a touch pad.

Comment: @AStar, cheaper drawing tablets have been about the price of a mouse for years. There's no reason to subject yourself to drawing with a mouse. It's very common for people to consider/try drawing with a mouse first to kinda test the waters or just getting by with what you have, but it isn't worth. That said, I can understand the hesitation to buy a drawing tablet/graphics tablet since it's a very specific device so even if you buy one for like $60, it's still a considerable amount of money if you end up using it only a few times. Do yourself a favor and check out some articles on cheap tablets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In windows you can use [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) to do this.

Autohotkey accompanied with the script below, will essentially do a mouse click every time you press `b` key.

[Download the scripthere](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1bxlgcw2cztu7s/B%20to%20mousebtn%201.ahk) or alternatively copy it from below.

Once you have AHK installed, double click the script and it'll start running right away.

To close the script: Right-click the script in the system tray and choose to `Exit` the script

*Note that this essentially overrides your normal b key behavior, so be sure to exit the script when you don't need it anymore. Also, you could set multiple key combinations instead of a single key.*

---

...and here's the code, if you don't feel like downloading the file, or it's not available anymore.

```
b:: Click down
b Up:: Click up
```

Copy the code and paste it into notepad or something and save it as `.ahk`.

---

---

As a bonus:

If you want to click a key to activate it and click a key again to deactivate it, you could do it with this code:

```
b::
if toggle := !toggle 
   Click down
else 
   Click up
return
```

Comment: Oh yes, almost forgot. Alternatively your keyboard may come with software that can do this. For example all Logitech G series keyboards can do this ( Although using one of the G keys ). Many gaming keyboards should be able to do this.